# How to convert <script>alert("555");</script> to &lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;555&quot;);&lt;/srcipt&gt; before insert into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

In input i fill this data `<script>alert("555");</script>`

and then insert into mysql. And mysql was store `<script>alert("555");</script>`

how can i do for convert to `&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;555&quot;);&lt;/srcipt&gt;` before insert into mysql ?

Comment: Why would you encode it like that when inserting it into the database?

Comment: You dont need that really unless your question links to validating user input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct encoding / escaping / htmlentities needed when sending data from js to php, php to mysql, and for REST json responses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759480/what-is-the-correct-encoding-escaping-htmlentities-needed-when-sending-data)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php :

```
 htmlentities($str);
```